# Exit Sticky Immersion causes click in ImageView

Tags: java, android

In my app, I have an ImageView which is in Sticky Immersion screen mode. Every time the user swipes down to get the menu bar, it also causes a click on the ImageView(which triggers a sound to be played).

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Comment: I actually have the same problem. How'd you end up solving this? It'd be annoying to have to capture screen events that aren't simple touches.